# opening_database

Tags: oracle

When I try to create user in the sqlplus, it raises an error at line 1

> ORA-01219: database not open: queries allowed on fixed tables/views only.

How to correct this error? Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Your database isn't open. Open it using the below command.

```
alter database open;
```

Comment: There could be other issues that prevented the database from opening; to be safe, the DBA should probably shutdown the database and start it back up.  But the command above will be the quick fix; if there are more issues, you'll get more errors on the open command.

Comment: @MarkStewart, thats kind of where I was going. :)

Comment: The original poster really needs to look at the alert log to see why the database is not open. And hopefully the database is backed up, preferably using RMAN.